# Inconsistent population size when using tbl_svysummary after weighting with survey design package

Tags: r, survey, gtsummary, propensity-score-matching

I performed propensity score calculation using the `twang` package with the following code, and successfully extracted the weights using the `get.weights()` function. Subsequently, I created a survey design object using the `survey` package. However, when I use the `tbl_svysummary()` function, the reported population size is 18470, while my original dataframe contains 9786 observations. Why is there such a significant difference in population size, and how can I maintain the same population size during analysis?

```
#Propensity score
ps.RS_complet.gbm = ps(SITE ~ RA02 +  RA03 +  RA04_2 +  RA05 +  RA07_2 +  RA08_1 +  RA10,
                       estimand = "ATE",
                       data = RS.var.ps,
                       n.trees=5000,
                       interaction.depth=3,
                       shrinkage=0.005,
                       bag.fraction = 0.5,
                       n.minobsinnode = 10,
                       verbose=FALSE,
                       na.action = "na.omit")

#get weight IPW
RS.var.ps$w <- get.weights(ps.RS_complet.gbm)
RS.ps <- svydesign(ids=~1, weights=~RS.var.ps$w, data=RS.var.ps)

#tblsummary
RS.ps |>
  tbl_svysummary(
    by = "Centre" ) |>
  add_p() |>
  bold_p() |>
  bold_labels()
```

[image]

My population without IPW and survey design

[image]

Comment: `tbl_svysummary()` is not appropriate for summarizing data after weighting. It produces weighted counts, which are invalid, incorrectly computes the sample size as you noted (instead, it should report the effective sample size), and produces p-values, which are invalid balance statistics that should not be reported. Use a different function that is better designed for the analysis of propensity score weighted data.